# How to connect two gitlab services in the same job

Tags: selenium-webdriver, gitlab, gitlab-ci, devops, pipeline

I'm using gitlab.com to host my test repository, and I've created local runners on my machine using the windows binary (which by the way is fully functional). But I hit a snag when it came to generating test evidence.

My runners configured on my local machine look like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwtmu.png)

I want to be able to use gitlab-ci to perform my test automations and generate evidence using the selenium/video library, which records the browser as soon as it makes the connection with the selenium/standalone-chrome container, following the following scenario:

https://gist.github.com/alexandremariano4/2bf2bf73913d8029642390cda2dab92c

However, when the runner runs these containers, starting the pipeline, I saw that no content was being recorded.

As you can see in the photo below, when I commit to my repository, and the pipeline is running and doing the steps correctly, in the right corner of the image you can see the behavior of the selenium/video container, which cannot be connect to grid (localhost:4444)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgQsF.png)

I already did a "debug" in each one of the containers, executing the command "wget ​​localhost:4444" to verify if they were able to connect to selenium/standalone-chrome, and I noticed that the container of the runner, and of the standalone, if connect correctly, but the selenium/video container cannot find this route.

I already used the flag: FF_NETWORK_PER_BUILD: 1

that I was recommended in other posts, however, it did not work for me, it even made my script unable to create the grid.

I need to be able to connect my selenium/video container to the selenium/standalone-chrome container to record the browser and have the evidence, I would appreciate any help possible.

Comment: would be better if u could share ur ci job and the error which u get.

Comment: Off course! In fact, I don't have the error in the ci job, the situation is actually not being able to make the connection between the selenium/video container with the selenium/standalone-chrome container
As you can see in the following images, the 2 containers (runner and selenium/standalone) manage to connect correctly to localhost:4444 (address of the grid), while selenium/video cannot, causing it not to record anything
[Selenium Standalone Chrome console](https://imgur.com/a/ehPZpN2)
[Selenium Video Console](https://imgur.com/a/lsN8lnU)
[Runner Console](https://imgur.com/a/KQPhpZF)